# Как с помощью sql привести телефоны к виду: +7(900)-123-34-56

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть таблица tab с телефонами:

```
7(900) 122 24 55
7-900-123-34-57
79001233458
```

Как привести телефоны к виду: +7(900)-122-24-55

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Удалить все нецифровые символы и отформатировать в нужный формат. Например, используя [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace).

Comment: Пардон, Oracle же... ну тогда https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions163.htm#SQLRF06302